# Need Help with Integral Multiplication Rules

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having trouble solving this question. My initial approach was to identify 'u' as the second value (the square root of $x^4$ + 2. However, that was wrong. My next approach was to identify 'u' as the first value ($x^3$), however that was also wrong. Can someone please explain to me the right approach for this problem? Thank you!

Identify *u* and *du* for the integral below.
Reference: $\int \ f(g(x)) \ g'(x) \ dx$ ; *u* = g(x) and *du* = g'(x)dx

$\int x^3 \sqrt{x^4 + 2}$

Comment: If $u=x^4+2$, then $du = 4x^3\ dx$. Your initial approach is not wrong; you just need to multiply and divide the integral with the same number constant.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you so much! Just to clarify - in this problem, why do we omit the square root symbol for 'u'?

Comment: The square root would be the $f$: $f(\cdot) = \sqrt \cdot$.

Comment: Oh, okay. Once again, thank you so much for the clarification!